# EPPLUS AutoFit cells

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, epplus

how can i set autosize on my cells, based on the max length of one input.

```
using (rng = workSheet.Cells["A1:G1"])
{
    rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.DarkBlue);
    rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);

}

using (ExcelRange col = workSheet.Cells[2, 6, 7, 7])
{
    col.Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm";
    col.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;

}

for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
{
    workSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "RU_ID";
    workSheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "COR_REQ_ID";
    workSheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "RU_NAME";
    workSheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "PARENT_RU_NAME";
    workSheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "ADJUSTMENT_STATE";
    workSheet.Cells["F1"].Value = "COR_START";
    workSheet.Cells["G1"].Value = "COR_END";
}
...

rng.AutoFitColumns();
string path = @"D:\excel\test.xlsx";
Stream stream = File.Create(path);
excel.SaveAs(stream);
stream.Close();
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

}
```

The only thing that AutoFitColumn is doing is to bring the cell to the size of the header, as if i have the header as "STH" and the inputs as "Something good", "something to increase cell size" than AutoFitColumn will set the size based on "STH" not "something to increase cell size".
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at your lines:

```
using (rng = workSheet.Cells["A1:G1"])
...
rng.AutoFitColumns();
```

Notice you are call `AutoFitColumns` on the range of of your headers `A1:G1` so EPPlus is using only those cells to determine the width of the columns.

Just do this instead:

```
workSheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

since `Cells` in Epplus only contain cells with actual values so there is no real concern over efficiency.

Comment: Thanks. I did not think of that. :D