# EPPlus AutoFitColumns not working

Tags: epplus

Seems to be a few folks with this problem, and usually it's solved because they haven't loaded data yet. I've loaded my data, but the Autofit is still not working.

```
Dim fi As New FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName)
Dim pck As New ExcelPackage(fi)

Dim epWs As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My Sheet")
epWs.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(data, True)

With epWs.Cells("A1:G1")
    .AutoFilter = True
    .AutoFitColumns()
    .Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
    .Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.DodgerBlue)
    .Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White)
End With

pck.Save()
```

This results in a file where the columns are all their default widths. There are no formulas in any of the cells, and none are merged.

I then kicked it up and tried using BestFit, but this is also not working.

```
        For i = 1 To 7
            epWs.Column(i).BestFit = True
        Next
```

(weird how the Columns collection is not zero-based)

Anyway, does anyone have any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `AutoFitColumns` on the entire range, not just `A1:G1`.  Do something like:

```
epWs.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
```

See this for more info:

[EPPLUS AutoFit cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794133/epplus-autofit-cells/36795472#36795472)

Comment: @BrianLink no problem, glad it worked.  Just remember to make the question as answered to close it out (and you get points).